# Dictionary into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have been extracting information from the coingecko API via pycoingecko

```
ren_daily_price=cg.get_coin_market_chart_range_by_id(id='republic-protocol',vs_currency='usd',from_timestamp=1585267200,to_timestamp=1616457600)
```

it gives me a object type dict

```
type(ren_daily_price)
```

dict

I am converting into a dataframe with this command and i get the below:

```
df=DataFrame.from_dict(ren_daily_price)
df
```

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47DPN.png)

you can see the unix number is representing the same date for each row.
How can i extract the date to act as index then i have the columns for prices, market_caps and Volume?

| Date | Prices | market_caps | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1585267200000 | 0.0456998 | 39721342.05347 | 2548106.9 |

Comment: What are the columns dtype?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to get the second item from the lists for all cells:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: To address the date index question, add this line first: `df.index = df.prices.map(lambda x: x[0])`